# Redirect previous page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have use query string to pass parameter to another page. But now I face the problem is how to pass value to previous page? For example, I have a page name forum and then forum page I have pass value to file page. Beside that, under file page there are having a child page which also refer to the query string. But then now i need to capture the query string that store in the forum page. May I know how can I do it?

The sequence of linking the page is forum --> file --> child

Comment: LocalStorage, cookies...did you try them?

Comment: Do you mean you want to use value passed from forum page on child page?

Comment: yeap... Can i do that？

Comment: You should use `Request["HTTP_REFERER"]`

Comment: For this you can use session variables OR just store the values passed from forum page in a variable in File form and then pass these new variables as query string on child form(though this is not the very good approach)

Comment: I have think it before but then because I need the value i dynamic! Mean that my value will change dynamically so I cant apply Session.

Comment: May I know Request["HTTP_REFERER"] this how to use?